# KendoUI - UI not refreshed after extracting repeating functions

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, observable, kendo-mvvm, kendo-observable

I have a view model, which has several collection properties with some repeating logic.
I need to be able to add a new empty object, to remove an object, and to ensure that every collection has at least one object, and if it is the only object, "Delete" button should be disabled.

To extract these common functions I extended k`endo.data.ObservableArray`:

```
function addEmpty() {
  this.push({});
}

function hasMoreThanOne {
  return this.length > 1;
}

var CoolObservableArray = kendo.data.ObservableArray.extend({
  init: function(data) {
    kendo.data.ObservableArray.fn.init.call(this, data);

    this.addEmpty = addEmpty.bind(this);
    this.hasMoreThanOne = hasMoreThanOne.bind(this);
  }
});
```

The problem is with `hasMoreThanOne` function. When I create an array with a single element, "Delete" button gets disabled - it is ok - but when I add new elements, it does not get enabled.

To refresh the UI kendo's `get` function need to be called, but it needs a parameter referencing to the property name, which will vary for each instance of `CoolObservableArray`, so I need to write repeating functions for each collection like `deleteXXXEnabled`, `deleteYYYEnabled`, etc.. How can I avoid it?

Here is the fiddle with problem reproduction: http://dojo.telerik.com/AFOMa/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source binding only renders the new object that you add to the `ObservableArray` because the change event which notifies the binding only indicates that a new item was added.

You can force the source binding to re-render the whole view by triggering a change event manually:

```
var CoolObservableArray = kendo.data.ObservableArray.extend({
    init: function (data, type) {
        kendo.data.ObservableArray.prototype.init.call(this, data, type);

        this.addEmpty = addEmpty.bind(this);
        this.deleteObject = deleteObject.bind(this);
        this.hasMoreThanOne = hasMoreThanOne.bind(this);    
        this.bind("change", function (e) {      
            if (e.action === "add" || e.action === "remove") {
                var that = this;

                // trigger another change which is not an "add" 
                // or "remove" or "itemchange" action
                setTimeout(function () {
                    that.trigger("change");
                }, 5);   
            }
        });  
    }
});

var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    wares: new CoolObservableArray([
        {title: "hampton sofa", price: 989}
    ])
});

kendo.bind("#waresWrapper", viewModel);
```

([updated demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/AFOMa/4))

Comment: Lars, many thanks, this is what I was looking for. But could you explain, why do I need `setTimeout`? If I omit it, a new element is added twice for the first time, after that new elements are added as usual. Why is it so?

Comment: @nativehr Without the timeout, the first change event is executed first, which causes the whole view to re-render (including the added element). Then the binding gets another change event with e.type === "add" and it renders another new element. So you end up with 2 additionally rendered ones.